# Stored Procedure is returning duplicate records

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following tables 7 tables:

1) Titles

```
ID    Title                                                        Author         
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     The Hidden Language of Computer Hardware and Software   Charles Petzold
2     Paths, Dangers, Strategies                              Nick Bostrom
3     The Smart Girl's Guide to Privacy                       Violet Blue
4     Introduction to Algorithms                              Thomas H. Cormen
5     Machine Learning in Action                              Peter Harrington
...
```

2) Themes

```
ID         Name
------------------------------------------
1          Science Fiction
2          Biography
3          Painting
...
```

3)   Subjects

```
ID           Name
-----------------------------------
1            Science 
2            Technology
3            Music
4            Geography
...
```

4)  Grades

```
ID            Name
------------------------------------
1             Grade 1
2             Grade 2
3             Grade 3
4             Grade 4
5             Grade 5
...
```

5) TitleThemeAssociation

```
TitleID         ThemeID
------------------------------------------
1               1
1               3
4               2
4               3
...
```

6) TitleSubjectAssociaton

```
TitleID          SubjectID
---------------------------------
1                1
1                3
2                1
2                3 
4                1
4                2  
...
```

7) TitleGradeAssociaton

```
TitleID              GradeID
1                    1
1                    2
1                    3
2                    1
2                    2
...
```

I have a stored procudure as below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTitlesPageWise]
       @PageIndex INT = 1
      ,@PageSize INT = 10
      ,@searchText NVARCHAR(250) = ''
      ,@PageCount INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      SET FMTONLY OFF;

select ROW_NUMBER() over 
       (
         ORDER BY [id] ASC
       ) as RowNumber,
        T.Id As [Title ID],
        T.Title,
        H.Theme,
        S.Subject,
        G.Grade
into #Results
From    Titles  T
Outer Apply
(
    Select  Stuff(( Select ', ' + Name 
                    From    Themes                  H
                    Join    TitleThemeAssociaton   TH  On  H.Id = TH.ThemeId
                    Where   TH.TitleId = T.Id 
                    For Xml Path('')), 1, 2, '') As Theme
    From    Themes
) H
Outer Apply
(
    Select  Stuff(( Select ', ' + Name 
                    From    Subjects                S
                    Join    TitleSubjectAssociation  TS  On  S.Id = TS.SubjectId
                    Where   TS.TitleId = T.Id 
                    For Xml Path('')), 1, 2, '') As Subject
    From    Subjects
) S
Outer Apply
(
    Select  Stuff(( Select ', ' + Name 
                    From    Grades                  G
                    Join    TitleGradeAssociation    TG  On  G.Id = TG.GradeId
                    Where   TG.TitleId = T.Id 
                    For Xml Path('')), 1, 2, '') As Grade
    From    Grades
) G
WHERE
    t.title Like @searchText + '%'
    AND
    (
        H.Theme Is Null
        Or      S.Subject Is Null
        Or      G.Grade Is Null
    )

      DECLARE @RecordCount INT
      SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*) FROM #Results

      SET @PageCount = CEILING(CAST(@RecordCount AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) / CAST(@PageSize AS DECIMAL(10, 2)))
      PRINT       @PageCount

      SELECT * FROM #Results
      WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1

      DROP TABLE #Results
END
```

I want distinct title ID and output is like as below but the query is giving the duplicate result. If Theme, Subject and Grade all there values are assigned that record should be excluded form the result. In the above case **Title ID 1** should be excluded because all three values are present there. I need help to fix the problem.

```
RowNumber    Title ID           Title          Theme       Subject     Grade
1            2  Paths, Dangers, Strategies      NULL       Science , Music  Grade 1, Grade 2
2            3  The Smart Girl's Guide to Privacy   NULL    NULL       NULL
3            4  Introduction to Algorithms   Biography, Painting    Science , Technology    NULL
4            5  Machine Learning in Action  NULL    NULL    NULL

.............
```

Comment: what is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/UVR89192)**

```
SELECT 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (ORDER BY [ID]) rn, 
       [ID],
       [Title],
       Subject = STUFF ((
                      SELECT ',' + S.[Name] 
                      FROM TitleSubjectAssociation TS
                      JOIN Subjects S
                        ON TS.SubjectId = S.Id 
                      WHERE TS.[TitleID] = T.[ID]
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''
                    ),
       Theme = STUFF ((
                      SELECT ',' + TH.[Name] 
                      FROM TitleThemeAssociation TA
                      JOIN Themes TH
                        ON TA.[ThemeID] = TH.[ID]
                      WHERE TA.[TitleID] = T.[ID]
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''
                    ),
       Grade = STUFF ((
                      SELECT ',' + G.[Name] 
                      FROM TitleGradeAssociation TG
                      JOIN Grades G
                        ON TG.[GradeID] = G.[ID]
                      WHERE TG.[TitleID] = T.[ID]
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''
                    )                                        
FROM Titles T;
```

If you need a filter you can try checking how many `,` are in the results. two `,` mean three elements.

```
WHERE len(Subject) - len(replace(Subject,',','')) != 2
  AND len(Theme) - len(replace(Theme,',','')) != 2
  AND len(Grade) - len(replace(Grade,',','')) != 2
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: I need to exclude the Title whose all three values Theme, Subject and Grade are present. In the above dataset, Title ID 1 should be excluded because all three values are present.

Comment: You didnt say anythig about that before :( Are you sure is only 3? Your data suggest there are more rows on each table

Comment: There are thousand of records in the tables and I need to exclude those records from the result which contains all the three values for Theme, Subject, and Grade. In the post, I have shown only a few records and there Title ID 1 has all the values and the record is removed from the resultset.

Comment: This doesn't satisfy my query. I need to exclude those titles which at least one value for Theme, Subject and Grade. If any of title has either Theme or Subject or Grade should be displayed in the result set. In the above test result set Title 1 has Theme, Subject and Grade present that is excluded.

Comment: Your requirement isnt clear. Do extra effort and explain all your condition with example on the question and let me know.